# How to make http requests using HTTP Intercepters

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement an angular application where I will make API calls to backend to get data. How can I create an Interceptor to make requests(GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) to backend urls. Also there are some specif routes that require an authorisation token.

Also, I want to handle specif tasks based on response status codes. If backend returns 401 or 500, 202 (has a refresh token) then I want to handle them accordingly. Also, is there any way to subscribe to the request from angular components.

As a beginner I dont have much idea how to create this in flexible way, so that if my application grows in future that it will not create any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following interceptor template to handle sending token in header ,refresh token and handle errors based on response status

```
import {
    HttpRequest,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpHeaders,
    HttpClient
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpConfigInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        const token = "my-token-string-from-server";

        //Authentication by setting header with token value
        if (token) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'Authorization': token
                }
            });
        }

        if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        }

        request = request.clone({
            headers: request.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json')
        });

        return next.handle(request).pipe(
            catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (error.status == 401 && error.error) {
                    return this.refreshToken(next, request);
                }
                return throwError(this.handleError(error));
            }));
    }

    handleError(error) {
        if (error.status == 400) {

        } else if (error.status == 422) {

        } else if (error.status = 404) {

        }
    }

    refreshToken(next, request): Observable<any> {
        var header = new HttpHeaders({
            "refreshToken": "refreshToken",
            "token": "token"
        });
        var url = environment.apiUrl + "/refreshToken";
        return this.httpClient.get(url, { headers: header }).pipe(
            flatMap(response => {
                //console.log(response);
                // save new token
                request = request.clone({ headers: request.headers.set('token', (<any>response).token) });
                return next.handle(request).pipe(
                    catchError(error => {
                        return throwError(this.handleError(error))
                    })
                )
            }),
        )
    }

}
```